# Bloqueio de senha após 5 tentativas

Tags: visual-basic-6

Criei a rotina que conta nº de tentativas do usuário ao logar no sistema, caso erre a senha por cinco vezes o sistema bloqueia o usuário. Porém meu código não está levando em conta o código de usuário(login de acesso), ou seja, sempre colocando usuários diferentes nas cinco tentativas, na quinta tentativa o sistema irá bloquear o usuário que foi tentado por último.
Coloquei na tabela 'usuarios' a coluna 'tentativa', porém ele fica contando sempre + 1 mesmo mudando o login do usuário.
Alguém consegue ajudar?

```
--variável
Private fiContador As Integer

--código
Private Sub cmdEntrar_Click()

If txtSenha.Text <> lTBUsuarios("senha") Then  'Rotina que conta as tentativas de login

lsql = ("SELECT tentativa FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text)
MsgBox lsql

    fiContador = fiContador + 1
        If lTBUsuarios("tentativa") >= 5 Then
            MensagemErro "O usuário foi inativado."
                txtLogin.SetFocus

            lsql = "UPDATE USUARIOS SET status = '" & "INATIVO" & "', tentativa = '" & "0" & "' WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text & ""
                gBDSistemaIntegrado.Execute lsql
        Else
            'fazer 1, 2, 3, 4, e 5 if vendo quantos registros de tentativa tem para o usuário
            'em cada um deles colocar o valor do fiContador = 1, 2, 3, 4,  ou 5

            lsql = "UPDATE USUARIOS SET tentativa = '" & fiContador & "' WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text & ""
                gBDSistemaIntegrado.Execute lsql

            MensagemErro "Senha inválida. Tentativa " & fiContador & " de 5."
                    txtSenha.Text = ""
                    txtSenha.SetFocus

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Editei agora, veja.

Comment: agora só falta a parte que pega o ficontador daquele usuário, e não da variável que conta pra todos.

Comment: Não consegui montar esta parte, a lógica tenho, só não consigo aplicar na prática do código.

Comment: Antes da linha "fiContador = fiContador + 1" você precisa fazer um SELECT tentativa FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = txtLogin.Text e guardar o valor em ficontador, que é pra pegar o contador daquela pessoa, e aumentar um nele. e não no da tentativa anterior. assim, o ficontador + 1 estará aumentando o anterior só daquela pessoa.

Comment: lsql = ("SELECT tentativa FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text)

Comment: isso, e tem que guardar o retorno em ficontador. na linha logo antes do ficontador = ficontador + 1

Comment: Fiz o select, agora como guardo o contador para pegar só naquela pessoa?

Comment: só guardar o retorno da query em ficontador, da mesma forma que vc pega senha e outras coisas., de resto acho que nao precisa mexer em mais nada

Comment: Sim, não consigo fazer este retorno neste caso aqui...

Comment: bom, precisa dar o execute, e ver como é que pega o retorno. Eu não uso VB, precisa ver como faz com as outras coisas (tipo pegar senha), a sintaxe é a mesma. Veja em outro select como é feito. No lugar do msxbox vc dá o Execute e pega o valor de alguma maneira com fiContador = algumacoisa field(1) ou coisa do tipo. Eu suponho que tenha outros lugares do seu código onde vc pega retorno de select, para ver a sintaxe correta.

Comment: fiContador = lTBUsuarios.Fields("tentativa").Value  'Rotina que guarda variável 'tentativa' do usuário logado

Comment: Testei e deu certo, muito obrigado pelo macete....

Comment: Seria legal você postar o código resolvido no campo abaixo, de respostas, e marcar como resolvido clicando no V verdinho ao lado das setas de votação. Assim, pode servir de referência para outros colegas de site.

Comment: Feitoria........

Answer (score 1):

```
If txtSenha.Text <> lTBUsuarios("senha") Then  'Rotina que conta as tentativas de login
    'lsql = ("SELECT tentativa FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text)

    gsFiContador = lTBUsuarios.Fields("tentativa").Value  'Rotina que guarda variável 'tentativa' do usuário
    gsFiContador = gsFiContador + 1

    'MsgBox gsFiContador

        If lTBUsuarios("tentativa") >= 5 Then
            MensagemErro "O usuário excedeu número de tentativas e está inativo. Contate o administrador do sistema."
                txtLogin.SetFocus

            lsql = "UPDATE USUARIOS SET status = '" & "INATIVO" & "', tentativa = '" & "0" & "' WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text & ""
                gBDSistemaIntegrado.Execute lsql
        Else
            lsql = "UPDATE USUARIOS SET tentativa = '" & gsFiContador & "' WHERE id_usuario = " & txtLogin.Text & ""
                gBDSistemaIntegrado.Execute lsql

            MensagemErro "Senha inválida. Tentativa " & gsFiContador & " de 5."
                    txtSenha.Text = ""
                    txtSenha.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Melhor ainda, aproveitou o select anterior. Se quiser incrementar, pode colocar SELECT nome, senha, **tentativa + 1** FROM... e até tirar a linha do soma um, OU no update fazer SET tentativa = tentativa + 1. Mas são só possibilidades, claro.